# matlib graphing every entry, want combined totals for each country

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pandas-groupby

I've done everything I can think of to get this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nationality': ['united states', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'nigeria', 'nigeria', 'united states', 'nigeria', np.nan, 'france', 'nigeria', 'nigeria', 'nigeria'], 'worldcat_libcount': [128.0, 58.0, 17.0, 89.0, 295.0, 3.0, 71.0, np.nan, 26.0, 6.0, 8.0, 20.0]})
print (df)
      nationality  worldcat_libcount
0   united states              128.0
1         unknown               58.0
2         unknown               17.0
3         nigeria               89.0
4         nigeria              295.0
5   united states                3.0
6         nigeria               71.0
7             NaN                NaN
8          france               26.0
9         nigeria                6.0
10        nigeria                8.0
11        nigeria               20.0
```

into a graph that shows the count per country. Rows containing the same country should be considered the same x value - but I'm not sure how to tell pandas or matplotlib that. So I get a graph that looks like this:

[counting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxX9M.png)

Any advice for what I should be doing so that Nigeria isn't multiple points would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you need `bar` plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregate data with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `sum` and then plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
s = df.groupby('nationality')['worldcat_libcount'].sum()
s.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Ahhh okay cool- thanks for the breakdown! I had tried to add .plot on the same line I was using .groupby and it failed horribly....distinguishing between Series and Dataframe continues to plague my approach, I see. Thanks again for the help.